# My app crashes randomly while playing

Tags: sdk, lua, coronasdk

I'm having a problem running my app. When I execute the game I can play until de game decides to crash randomly giving me this error: **Invalid memory access of location 0xc rip=0x1006eb08d** and Corona SDK gets closed.

My game is a kind of Cut the Rope with 1, 2 or 3 cords with a fruit on it, the game asks for the correct fruit and the player must cut the correct cord to achieve the next level.

Anyone knows why I have this error? Or what should I have to look on my code to see what's doing this error?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I tried to narrow why it's crashing and I think the problem it's when I paint the line to cut the rope. That's how I did the code:

```
function drawLine(e) 

        print('drawLine: '..e.phase)

        if(e.phase == 'began') then
            initX = e.x
            initY = e.y
        elseif(e.phase == 'moved') then
            line = display.newLine(initX, initY, e.x, e.y)
            physics.addBody(line, 'static')
            line.isSensor = true
            line:addEventListener('collision', ropeCollision)
            line.strokeWidth = 0
            lines:insert(line)
        elseif(e.phase == 'ended') then
            display.remove(lines)
            lines = nil
            lines = display.newGroup()
        end
end
```

That function paint a line that when collisions with a rope, It calls to the ropeCollision function that controls if the rope has to be cut or not. But doing a print with the phase, I saw that it does a lot of calls to that event. Am I doing well? Or there is a better way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: To broad questions, give more details!

Comment: If you can give mo details about the crash we can help you out more.

Comment: Also you can view here: https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/29404-doing-a-build-for-an-android-device-i-get-segmentation-fault-11/

Comment: Thanks to both for answer. I edited my post, I'm not sure if that's the problem but I'm doing some tests with that part of the code.